# Dummy VLAN settings and networks issues

Tags: networking, vlan

I need to speak tomorrow the network engineer and I would like to understand his so apologise for the Dummy question:

In the school we have a cab with a 24 port Netgear manageable switch with an admin and curriculum VLAN settings.

Usually, as I over heard, in the morning and around 4.30pm there are a slowdown period on the computers which connect to this switch.

No one could track this back yet. Questions:

1. What is the best way to track back this slowdown
2. Would it be a temporary solution to physical separate the two network with 2 switches
3. If that would work how can I link them together to be able to see the curriculum from the admin side.
4. Do I need an extra router then?

Too many questions but I have no clue where to start and the gentleman will be paid by hours... can you see where I am coming from?:)

Any comment would be appreciated and please send links if you down vote the question:)

Andras

Comment: So it's slower at starting time and quitting time?  How many users?  What are they all likely doing at that time?  That's probably the trouble right there.

Comment: thanks Josh yes it is still under investigation but I hoped that someone has an idea for the best practice or an app that could help to find the root of this